# Oracle SQL Developer Mac OS cannot bulk insert into SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, macos, bulkinsert, oracle-sqldeveloper, csv

I'm trying to import a set of flat files into an SQL server database. I downloaded and installed Oracle SQL Developer for Mac OS. I installed the proper plugin and can connect to the database fine, create tables and perform queries. The problem is I'm trying to use bulk insert to import some tab delimited files into the database. Thing is though, the bulk insert doesn't seem to work. The bulk insert code is as follows

```
BULK INSERT sessions
FROM '/.../sessions.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',ROWTERMINATOR='\n')
```

That's the error log I get

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
BULK INSERT sessions
Error at Command Line:1 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near 'sessions'.
Error starting at line 2 in command:
FROM '/..../sessions.txt'
Error at Command Line:2 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Error starting at line 3 in command:
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',ROWTERMINATOR='\n')
Error at Command Line:3 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Answer (score 0):

`BULK INSERT` is a statement executed on the SQL Server. The file names involved are interperted in the context of the NT deployed SQL Server instance. `'/.../sessions.txt'` is not a valid NT filename, NT uses `\` for directories delimiter in full path file names.

Comment: Tried it. Still doesn't work. Could it have something to do with the path name format in Mac OS (No drive name at beginning of path)? If so, is there a way around that?

Comment: The path must be a file on the SQL Server host (including an UNC file name provided proper network access right are in place), not a file on your Mac.

Comment: What if the SQL server is an Amazon RDS instance?

Comment: The the name must be a file on the Amazon RDS host server. You should use instead a tool that does the bulk copy from a client file, like [`bcp.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). If you cannot run `bcp.exe` on your Mac client, the API of relevant is the [TDS Internal bcp functions](http://www.freetds.org/reference/a00287.html). Happy coding!

Comment: Also, the RDS blessed way is described in [Importing Data to a Microsoft SQL Server DB Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ImportData.SQLServer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try `0x0a` as row terminator:

```
BULK INSERT sessions
FROM '/.../sessions.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='\t', ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a')
```